# not knowing how(Linux command) to restart oracle database 12.1.0 server

Tags: oracle

Our developers got below error:

> ```
> PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT"
> ERROR LOG:
> Job aborted due to stage failure: 
> Aborting TaskSet 0.0 because task 0 (partition 0)
> cannot run anywhere due to node and executor blacklist.
> Most recent failure:
> Lost task 0.2 in stage 0.0 (TID 2, w3.cdhnode1.modak.com, executor 7): java.sql.SQLException: ORA-04036: PGA memory used by the instance exceeds PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT
> ORA-06512: at "SYS.XMLTYPE", line 138
> ```

I am using below commands to increase `PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT` but it needs to restart the oracle database. I am not knowing how to do it I checked all the content in google but couldn't find any.

```
QL> show parameter pga 
NAME            TYPE                      VALUE
----------------------- ------------------------- -----------------------------
pga_aggregate_limit     big integer               2G
pga_aggregate_target    big integer               120M
SQL> alter system set pga_aggregate_limit=1G scope=spfile;
System altered.
SQL> alter system set pga_aggregate_target=1G scope=spfile;
System altered.
```

Please guide me to restart oracle database.

Comment: If you app is _exceeding_ the current pga limit,why are you _reducing_ the pga limit?  And I must ask, if you know how to do this and, more importantly, have the _authority_ to do this, how can you _not_ know how to restart the db?  Ok, I'll give you a hint.  It's a command you issue with sqlplus - the same sqlplus you were using when you issued the 'alter system' commands.  See the sqlplus reference manual.

Comment: i have increase PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT from 5G to 7G.
but same error and restrated database aswell.
any help here will be much appricieated.

Comment: i have total physical memory of 15G should i increase this and PGA_AGGREGATE_LIMIT also????